# Elasticsearch network host cant be set?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have downloaded ES and configure the yml file for network host to be 0.0.0.0. Then when I start it up with **bin/elasticsearch**, it gives me the following error.

```
172.16.1.237:9300}, bound_addresses {[::]:9300}
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: bootstrap checks failed
initial heap size [268435456] not equal to maximum heap size [2147483648]; this can cause resize pauses and prevents mlockall from locking the entire heap
max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process likely too low, increase to at least [65536]
please set [discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes] to a majority of the number of master eligible nodes in your cluster
max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] likely too low, increase to at least [262144]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapCheck.check(BootstrapCheck.java:125)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapCheck.check(BootstrapCheck.java:85)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapCheck.check(BootstrapCheck.java:65)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.validateNodeBeforeAcceptingRequests(Bootstrap.java:178)
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.start(Node.java:373)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:193)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:252)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:96)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:91)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.SettingCommand.execute(SettingCommand.java:54)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:91)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:53)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:70)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:63)
Refer to the log for complete error details.
```

What would be the issue?

Comment: what is the cluster setup you have and what is the hardware config for your server? Please post your configuration file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the elasticsearch.yml file to elasticsearch.json inside config folder and add:

```
{
    "network" : {
        "host" : "0.0.0.0"
    }
}
```

OR Try to start elasticsearch server with this command

```
elasticsearch -Des.network.host=0.0.0.0
```